# What's wrong with this sphere?

Tags: critique, shadows, sprite

[image: sphere]

Really, It doesn't look right. When I compare it to other spheres, I can't tell what's wrong with it.

It may be the cast-lighting, but maybe something bigger.

What's wrong with this sphere?

Comment: The wrong part is that it is not clear what are you talking about. :o) Yes it has some faults. But remember that the site looks for some quality on the questions. Not a philosophical aproach.

Answer (score 1):

Your sphere seems to have rays being cast. Notice the light and then there's almost rays coming from it:

[image: sphere]

To try and indicate what I'm seeing:

[image]

You shouldn't be able to see such defined lines in the sphere. Keep in mind its supposed to be a 3D shape so if the light is hitting from the bright point you have it at then around the halfway mark it would start to diffuse maybe something like this, this is really really rough but I tried to emphasize the line I'm referring to:

[image]

To further explain here is with some markings. Since a perfect sphere is symmetrical than wherever your light hits you need to visualize where the "dark side" would fall:

[image]

Yours looks flat as a result of these two things IMO.

Keep in mind different types of materials will make different effects. If your sphere is some translucent material then the light will be very different.